# [android]use mediacodec and ffmpeg to generate .ts file, but the generated ts file has no image cover

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediacodec

i went into a problem as mentioned bellow;
i use android frameworks's Mediacodec API to encode camera preview flow from opengl texture,and wish to generate a ts file;
since Mediacodec does not support generating ts file, so i use ffmpeg to do so;
every thing is OK, the ts file is successfully generated, and it can be played by media player either on my android or pc, but there are still 2 problems bothering me;

1. **the video file does not have a image co, wherever the xxx.ts is shown on my android phone or PC;**
2. **when i move the xxx.ts onto my pc(windows), right click the file to check its attribute, the attribute frame-rate is also empty;**

Does any one have ideas on these isssues?

the **encoder mediacodec configuration** is as bellow:

```
mBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, width, height);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, 
                  MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 4 * 1024 * 1024);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);
        
mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
mEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
mInputSurface = mEncoder.createInputSurface();
mEncoder.start();

mFFmpegMuxer = new FFmpegMuxer();
mFFmpegMuxer.prepare();
```

FFmepgMuxer->prepare() which is also known as **ffmpeg muxer's configuration** is as bellow：

```
mOutputFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();

AVOutputFormat * outputFormat = av_guess_format(nullptr, "xxx.ts", nullptr);
mOutputFormatCtx->oformat = outputFormat;
AVStream *stream = avformat_new_stream(mOutputFormatCtx, nullptr);
stream->codecpar->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
stream->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA;
stream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
stream->codecpar->codec_tag = av_codec_get_tag(mOutputFormatCtx->oformat->codec_tag, 
                                               AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
stream->codecpar->width = 1080;
stream->codecpar->height = 1200;
stream->codecpar->bit_rate = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
stream->time_base.num = 1;
stream->time_base.den = 25;
mOutputStreamInd = stream->index;

if (mOutputFormatCtx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
    mOutputFormatCtx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}
avio_open2(&mOutputFormatCtx->pb, outputPath.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, nullptr, nullptr);

av_dict_set(&opts, "movflags", "faststart", 0);
avformat_write_header(mOutputFormatCtx, &opts);
av_dict_free(&opts);
```

everytime the mediacodec sucessfully encoded a packet, **the packet will be enqueue into ffmpeg**:

```
void FFmpegMuxer::enqueueBuffer(uint8_t *data, int offset, int size, long pts, bool keyFrame) {
    if (mPacket == nullptr) { mPacket = av_packet_alloc(); }
    av_init_packet(mPacket);
    mPacket->stream_index = mOutputStreamInd;
    mPacket->size = size;
    mPacket->data = data + offset;
    if (mRecStartPts == 0) {
        mRecStartPts = pts;
        mPacket->pts = 0;
        mPacket->dts = 0;
    } else {
        int64_t dstPts = pts - mRecStartPts;
        dstPts = av_rescale_q(dstPts, AV_TIME_BASE_Q,
                              mOutputFormatCtx->streams[mOutputStreamInd]->time_base);
        mPacket->pts = dstPts;
        mPacket->dts = dstPts;
    }
    if (keyFrame) {
        mPacket->flags = AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
    }
    int status = av_interleaved_write_frame(mOutputFormatCtx, mPacket);
    if (status < 0) {
        ..........
    }
    av_packet_unref(mPacket);
}
```

when the **recording is required to be stopped**, the code is as bellow:

```
av_write_trailer(mOutputFormatCtx);
```

the code snippets are information i could supply, can any one find out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

finally i find out what is wrong;
the ts is real-time bit flow, so i need to insert sps and pps before every i frame;
that is the answer.